# Getting Tomcat to reload a web app with a static context

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat6, hotdeploy

I have a `Host` that doesn't automatically deploy all web apps.

```
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
```

But I do want the **dreambear** web app to automatically reload without a restart, for development purposes (hence this is on SO, not Server Fault).

*Catalina/localhost/dreambear.xml*:

```
<Context reloadable="true">
    <Parameter name="gamePageUrl" value="http://****/dreambear.html" />
</Context>
```

I deploy the web app by putting dreambear.war in the webapps dir. Unfortunately, it doesn't automatically get reloaded:

- (Host:unpackWARs = false): The new version of the WAR is not detected
- (Host:unpackWARs = true): The new version of the WAR is not unpacked
- (Host:unpackWARs = true): If I delete the unpacked directory, the new WAR will be unpacked but not deployed.

Is there a way to achieve what I want? I don't want to enabled `autoDeploy` because my context xml will be deleted every time I put in a new WAR ([see here](http://stein.everybody.org/brain/tomcat-deletes-context-descriptor-on-redeployment/)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried some combinations, and **none of them will redeploy from the WAR file with `autoDeploy` set to `false`.**

Setting `reloadable` to `true` in `Context` wont work, since the docs state

> Set to true if you want Catalina to
>   monitor classes in /WEB-INF/classes/
>   and /WEB-INF/lib for changes, and
>   automatically reload the web
>   application if a change is detected.

I've also tried reloading from the manager web app

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/reload?path=/dreambear
```

However, this **too does not take changes from the war**

> This can be useful when the web
>   application context is not reloadable
>   and you have updated classes or
>   property files in the /WEB-INF/classes
>   directory or when you have added or
>   updated jar files in the /WEB-INF/lib
>   directory.

The [manager docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Reload_An_Existing_Application) are more clear on this

> Currently, application reloading (to
>   pick up changes to the classes or
>   web.xml file) is not supported when a
>   web application is deployed directly
>   from a WAR file. It only works when
>   the web application is deployed from
>   an unpacked directory. If you are
>   using a WAR file, you should undeploy
>   and then deploy or deploy with the
>   update parameter the application again
>   to pick up your changes.

Comment: I guess I'll just resort to uploading the app as a directory instead of a war. I vaguely remember from my school days that works better in Tomcat anyway.